# How do I run retropi when my raspberrypi is connected to my mac via ethernet?

Tags: pi-3, retropie, macos

I am new to this so sorry if this is a stupid question. I'm trying to start the retropie desktop screen, but I'm a bit lost on how to do it.

- I have installed the retropie disk image to the micro sd card
- downloaded some roms as well.
- I have connected my raspberrypi to my mac via ethernet and I'm sharing my mac's internet.

I can see the retropie on the `Network` tab, but I don't know which script I need to run to be able to start the whole thing.

Thanks

Here is a picture of what I'm seeing.

[image]

Comment: Is the pi connected to a display?

Comment: Are you trying to run RetroPi *on your Mac*, from the Pi?

Comment: Connect a keyboard and screen to the Pi

Comment: hi there thanks for the answers I was wondering more if I could just run it without the display from my computer. I tried `ssh retropi_ip_address` but it gives me an error. Thanks

Comment: Again, are you trying to run the RetroPi on your mac? AFAIK, you can't do that.  You'd have to find some way to just use the screen from your mac as the monitor for the pi.  Otherwise, it sounds like you're trying to emulate the Pi via your Mac...?